# "Because of" construction in German

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, punctuation

Trying to translate the following sentence, I wondered how the construction is formed in German:

> There was a delay because of technical problems.

I'd say:

> ... technischer Probleme gab es eine Verzögerung.

[dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=because%20of) says *because* would be translated into the following words, so it doesn't matter which one I use, does it?

> Aufgrund technischer Probleme gab es eine Verzögerung.
>
> Infolge technischer Probleme gab es eine Verzögerung.
>
> Punkto technischer Probleme gab es eine Verzögerung.
>
> Wegen technischer Probleme gab es eine Verzögerung.

And no punctuation mark is needed as in *Wegen technischer Probleme, gab es eine Verzögerung*. Am I right?

Comment: I think "Aufgrund ..." is also what Deutsche Bahn announces a thousand times a day.

Comment: Ich denke, wie  Eugene Seidel im Kommentar anmerkt, dass "In Punkto" gemeint ist, zögerte aber das mit zu korrigieren, da es aus dict.cc stammen soll (fehlt das 'in' da auch?). Dazu kommt, dass es nicht passt (auch schon gesagt).

Comment: @userunknown Folge dem Link: Ja, das ist so in dict.cc zu finden – und ich kenne das auch nicht in dieser Form, ich sehe das wie Du/ihr. Interessant die Erläuterung in Klammern dahinter: „[bezüglich] [meist österr. od. schweiz.]“.

Comment: Leiwand Österreich/Schweiz!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Aufgrund* (lit. "on cause") would be my favourite. It suits the technical/formal character best (and a little bit better than *wegen* which is common for "because of" in non-formal contexts and is also okay here.)

*Infolge* (lit. "in consequence") would be my second choice, it seems somehow (though only a tiny little bit) overblown to me.

*Punkto* is not used very often and seems strange to me.

You are right, no comma is needed.

Answer (score 6):

It matters, which you use :).

*Aufgrund* und *infolge* aren't different in this case. There is a difference, but I don't know a case where the difference would matter. **Edit**: Also pay attention to the other answers, they provide more information about *aufgrund* und *infolge*.

However, *punkto* isn't used. Never heard it before.

*Wegen* is more colloquial. If you don't want to sound technical, *wegen* is perfect.

Comment: *Infolge* betont den Zusammenhang von A und B, wobei das eine (zwangsläufig) auf das andere folgt. *Aufgrund* stellt die Ursache **oder den Urheber** in den Vordergrund, daher kann *infolge* nicht immer verwendet werden, wo *aufgrund* steht. Der Teilsatz *infolge des schwachen Dollars* klingt genauso hakelig, wie *infolge von Vorgaben* oder *infolge der Richtlinie* etc. Kompletter Beispielsatz: *Zwar sollte infolge des schwachen Dollars die Liquidität in naher Zukunft wieder steigen, gibt man sich an der Börse dennoch vorsichtig.* Es klingt nicht ganz falsch, aber sehr ungewohnt zumindest.

Comment: @Em1: Dankeschön, das war mir nicht bewusst =)

Comment: _in puncto_ (or _in punkto_) s.th. is perfectly idiomatic German but it does not apply here. It is equivalent to "with regard to" or "concerning" s.th., hence it does not belong among OP's examples.

Comment: @EugeneSeidel See @userunknown’s and my comments below the question. We are with you.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to change the order of words, you can say

> Es gab eine Verzögerung aufgrund technischer Probleme.
>
> Es gab eine Verzögerung wegen technischer Probleme.

No comma needed.

Comment: This is O.K., but keep in mind that German is somewhat more of a left-[branching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_%28linguistics%29) language than English. If we split the phrase in two, then "there was a delay / es gab eine Verzögerung", while truncated, carries enough information to convey the essential message, so we call this the "head";  "due to technical problems / wegen technischer Probleme", on the other hand, cannot stand on its own: it modifies the head, so we call this the "modifier". As German has a stronger tendency to branch to the left, OP's word order is more "natural".

Answer (score 3):

Ergänzend zu den anderen Antworten:

***Punkto*** in diesem Kontext bitte **nicht** verwenden.

[Es heißt tatsächlich *punkto* ohne *in*.]

Bei dict.cc steht "meist österr. od. schweiz.", im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/punkto) "Gebrauch: österreichisch, schweizerisch, sonst veraltet" - und ich glaube mich zu erinnern, das hin und wieder (selten) von Schweizern oder Österreichern gehört zu haben.

ABER: es heißt offenbar immer *hinsichtlich*, *bezüglich*, als Übersetzung für *because of* ist es schlichtweg falsch.